# DocumentDB performance issues

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When running from DocumentDB queries from C# code on my local computer a simple DocumentDB query takes about 0.5 seconds in average. Another example, getting a reference to a document collection takes about 0.7 seconds in average. Is this to be expected? Below is my code for checking if a collection exists, it is pretty straight forward - but is there any way of improving the bad performance?

```
// Create a new instance of the DocumentClient
var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), AuthorizationKey);

// Get the database with the id=FamilyRegistry
var database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(db => db.Id == "FamilyRegistry").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

// Get the document collection with the id=FamilyCollection
var documentCollection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery("dbs/" 
    + database.Id).Where(c => c.Id == "FamilyCollection").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

stopWatch.Stop();

// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
var ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

// Format and display the TimeSpan value.
var elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00} seconds, {1:00} milliseconds",
    ts.Seconds,
    ts.Milliseconds );

Console.WriteLine("Time taken to get a document collection: " + elapsedTime);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Average output on local computer:

```
Time taken to get a document collection: 0 seconds, 752 milliseconds
```

In another piece of my code I'm doing 20 small document updates that are about 400 bytes each in JSON size and it still takes 12 seconds in total. I'm only running from my development environment but I was expecting better performance.

Comment: Have you tried running this in the same data center as your DocumentDB? I've experienced large (~250ms) latency when crossing the data center boundary with DocumentDB operations. However, if I call it from an instance running in the same Azure data center, I get low latency (~10ms).

Comment: @LarryMaccherone No I have not, I have only ran my code from my local developement environment as of yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, this can be done end to end in **~9 milliseconds** with DocumentDB. I'll walk through the changes required, and why/how they impact results below.

The very first query always takes longer in DocumentDB because it does some setup work (fetching physical addresses of DocumentDB partitions). The next couple requests take a little bit longer to warm the connection pools. The subsequent queries will be as fast as your network (the latency of reads in DocumentDB is very low due to SSD storage).

For example, if you modify your code above to measure, for example 10 readings instead of just the first one like shown below:

```
using (DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), AuthorizationKey))
{
    long totalRequests = 10;

    var database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(db => db.Id == "FamilyRegistry").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    for (int i = 0; i < totalRequests; i++)
    {
        watch.Start();
        var documentCollection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery("dbs/"+ database.Id)
            .Where(c => c.Id == "FamilyCollection").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine("Finished read {0} in {1}ms ", i, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        watch.Reset();
    }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

I get the following results running from my desktop in Redmond against the Azure West US data center, i.e. about **50 milliseconds**. These numbers may vary based on the network connectivity and distance of your client from the Azure DC hosting DocumentDB:

```
Finished read 0 in 217ms
Finished read 1 in 46ms
Finished read 2 in 51ms
Finished read 3 in 47ms
Finished read 4 in 46ms
Finished read 5 in 93ms
Finished read 6 in 48ms
Finished read 7 in 45ms
Finished read 8 in 45ms
Finished read 9 in 51ms
```

Next, I switch to Direct/TCP connectivity from the default of Gateway to improve the latency from two hops to one, i.e., change the initialization code to:

```
using (DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), AuthorizationKey, new ConnectionPolicy { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct, ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp }))
```

Now the operation to find the collection by ID completes within **23 milliseconds**:

```
Finished read 0 in 197ms
Finished read 1 in 117ms
Finished read 2 in 23ms
Finished read 3 in 23ms
Finished read 4 in 25ms
Finished read 5 in 23ms
Finished read 6 in 31ms
Finished read 7 in 23ms
Finished read 8 in 23ms
Finished read 9 in 23ms
```

How about when you run the same results from an Azure VM or Worker Role also running in the same Azure DC? The same operation completes with about **9 milliseconds**!

```
Finished read 0 in 140ms
Finished read 1 in 10ms
Finished read 2 in 8ms
Finished read 3 in 9ms
Finished read 4 in 9ms
Finished read 5 in 9ms
Finished read 6 in 9ms
Finished read 7 in 9ms
Finished read 8 in 10ms
Finished read 9 in 8ms
Finished read 9 in 9ms
```

So, to summarize:

- For performance measurements, please allow for a few measurement samples to account for startup/initialization of the DocumentDB client.
- Please use TCP/Direct connectivity for lowest latency.
- When possible, run within the same Azure region.
- If you follow these steps, you can get great performance and you'll be able to get the best performance numbers with DocumentDB.

Comment: I'm getting 10x the time that you are getting, but then again I'm calling the DocumentDB service from Europe. Still, I'm not getting such bad performance when calling the Azure Table Storage for some reason. I've added a PasteBin with my results here http://pastebin.com/3u1VpgRB

Comment: @Aravind, I get no where near your performance (~250ms vs your ~23ms) when running at my work, even after initialization and warming. I'm not hitting it from North Carolina to a US East data center. Another difference for me is that I'm using node.js which I understand doesn't use TCP/Direct, but I also wondered about your mention of "two hops". Does that apply to  node.js usage? What is the purpose of the second hop? CORS?

Is it possible that as a Microsoft employee, your experiments have an expedited network connection to your data center? Then again, it could just be my bad work connection

Comment: @IngeHenriksen, can you please send me a WireShark trace of the execution? Which region is your DocumentDB account in, and where's your client? DocumentDB is available in both West Europe and North Europe regions in Azure. And for contrast, where is the Azure Tables account?

Comment: @LarryMaccherone, for comparison, from my home internet connection, I'm getting 33 ms vs. 23 ms, so not a big difference. We can debug with a WireShark trace if you could send me one.

Comment: @AravindRamachandran I don't have WireShark, but I'm calling a US Central DocumentDB service from Northern Europe if that helps. I'm using v1.5 of the DocumentDB client.

Comment: DocumentDB is not available in Central US (yet). Perhaps this is the other way around? PS: you can email me at arramac@microsoft.com. Might be efficient to debug over a call. I'll report back findings to this thread.

Comment: @AravindRamachandran Im located in Northern Europe and tried to access a DocumentDB in West US. Now I have created a DocumentDB in Northern Europe, the performance is better but still about 60 ms where you get 9ms using your code example, see http://pastebin.com/08VQYh1X

Comment: @AravindRamachandran (see my comment above an hour ago) ... the results when running CreateDatabaseQuery() is even worse - it uses up to 5 seconds at the first call, see my code and results here http://pastebin.com/jU0r9wLj

Comment: I've filed a work item here to investigate the long first call latency - we'll take a look at optimizations here. Regarding 60 ms vs. 9 ms, I suspect this  is almost all network latency. Can you please let me know what numbers you see at http://azurespeedtest.azurewebsites.net/ for North Euro[e?

Comment: @AravindRamachandran 68ms for Northern Europe.