# Why is the first request to Azure Document DB much slower than subsequent requests?

Tags: c#, performance, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have read the Document DB [performance guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-performance-tips), but I still see a much slower first request to Document DB.  We are using the `client.OpenAsync()` tip and connecting in `Direct` mode over `TCP`.

I have written a sample program to repo this issue (this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinkuszyk/26189b4d6508a547133675e0bbfa5a31) has the full source including recording times):

```
var endpoint = "";
var key = "";

var connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy 
{
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
    ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp
};

var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), key, connectionPolicy);
var collection = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("test", "TestCollection");

await client.OpenAsync();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var test = new Test { Foo = $"Test doc {i}" };
    await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collection, test);     
}
```

Using `Gateway` mode over `HTTPS` I see these times:

[image]

And in `Direct` mode over`TCP` these:

[image]

As you can see, `Direct` mode over `TCP` is much faster for the subsequent requests, but the first request is still much slower.

Is there a reason for this?  And is there anything we can do to reduce the initial response time?

**UPDATE**

I'd forgotten that we proxy all HTTPS traffic out of our Azure VMs, which is why the `HTTPS` responses are much slower than `TCP` in my initial tests.

With the proxy off, and running 10 iterations (3 to warm up Document DB & the SDK, and 7 to profile), I now see response times of ~11ms for `Gateway` over `HTTPS` and ~7ms for `Direct` over `TCP`.

Comment: I'm convinced that there is something wonky about using the REST interface (which every SDK except the .NET one uses) outside of the same Azure data center. The delta between running it on nodejs hosted in the same Azure data center compared to DocumentDB operations from our own servers is not explained (by 40x) by the bandwidth and latency differences in the network within which our servers reside. It's not a problem for us since we run in the same data center, but I really wish someone at Azure would take a look at this issue.

Comment: The answer to your headline question though is not that surprising as it mimics the "warming" behavior that I see in other databases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocumentDB performance issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088927/documentdb-performance-issues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like one of the posters mentioned, this has been covered at [DocumentDB performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088927/documentdb-performance-issues)

The very first operation takes longer a couple of seconds in DocumentDB because the SDK does additional setup work like fetching physical addresses of DocumentDB data partitions. Subsequent operations will complete in the order of single-digit milliseconds (around 7ms for writes like in your screenshot, reads typically under 2ms).

Comment: Thanks @Aravind Ramachandran.  Please see my update above.  As you suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33090447/1288481, allowing some time for the server and SDK to warm up has increased the response times.

Answer (score 0):

DocumentDB provides low latency and high throughput at p99 level. To do that there is an amortization cost to establish the connections and pool them, downloading metadata to do efficient routing caching and many other optimizations at scale.  This is the reason why there is a bit of cost upfront.